# Jump to the last page

Tags: delphi, fastreport, delphi-10-seattle, quickreports

I am migrating reports from QuickReport to FastReports. In the old code I have the following:

```
if MyCheckBox.Checked then
      MyReport.LastPage;
```

I would call this in an AfterPrint event of a band, but I can´t seem to migrate this part of the code. 
How is it possible to jump to the last page using FastReports ?